# CopyTo function issue while copying folder contains files from one library to another Library using pnp js

Tags: sharepoint-2013, pnp-js

I am trying to copy the folder from one library to another library. But i am getting an error as below.

```
pnpWebsite.getFolderByServerRelativePath(...).copyTo is not a function TypeError: pnpWebsite.getFolderByServerRelativePath(...).copyTo is not a function.
```

I tried like below

```
var pnpWebsite = $pnp.sp.web;
    pnpWebsite.getFolderByServerRelativePath("Path").copyTo(LibraryUrl).then(function(res) { 
});
```

Am i doing any wrong. Please correct me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the document, pnp js does not provide the `getFolderByServerRelativePath("Path").copyTo(LibraryUrl)`

1. [folder copy](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/folders/#copy)
2. [folder copy by path](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/folders/#copy-by-path)

The closest to your code is [file copy](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/files/#copy).

My test code for your reference:

```
sp.web.getFileByServerRelativePath("/sites/dev/Doc/ccc.ps1").copyTo("/sites/dev/lib/ccc.ps1",false).then(res => console.log(res));
```